# DDD - aggregate roots in a very simple blog model

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

As an exercise I am trying to create a simple blog app in .NET, employing DDD. So far I have User, Topic and Comment classes. But the problem is how to link Comment with User and Topic? If I say that User and Topic are aggregate roots, where does Comment belong?

Comment: That question would never exist if you've followed DDD's theory. First, brainstorm and draw the possible scenarios, then code. For example, a topic can be thought as the first comment of a series of them, so there's no big distinction between them except the extras that a topic has (title, tags, etc)

Comment: Well I'm a complete noob in DDD and software architecture in general. But from what I've heard one should avoid generalization, that is if users think of a topic as a different thing from a comment, I should not model it as a comment.
I'm trying to brainstorm my model right now...

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates may have associations to other aggregate roots.

e.g. a comment may have an association to both topic and user.
Thats how I would model it anyway, aggregate roots are boundaries of consistency.
A Topic does not need to be consistent in any way with its comments, thus comments does not need to be part of that aggregate.
A user does not need to be consistent with all of his or her comments  so users does not need to know about comments either.

I would fetch the comments for a specific topic by the comment repository.
e.g.

```
var comments = commentRepo.FindCommentsForTopic(someTopic); 
//or by topic id for pragmatic reasons.
```